# How to create a more "correct" multi-use jQuery variable

Tags: jquery

So here is my question, or issue. I have written the below jQuery code, it's job is to load new page content, animate it with a slide, slide the old content out, and then destroy the old content.

I am pretty new to jQuery as I am trained as a designer and not a developer so please forgive anything thats not right but I am very proud of what I have come up with thus far.

My goal is to be able to slide the content in and out in different directions, currently its right to left always. My issue is that I don't see how to do this without creating new variables with each and every direction, which would be 8 different "clickAnimation" vars, far too many in my mind.

```
var clickAnimation = function() {
    $(document).on('click', linkLeft, function(e) {
        var url = $(this).attr('href');
        e.preventDefault();
        $('body').append('<div id="new_wrapper"></div>');
        $('#new_wrapper').load(url + ' #wrapper', function(){
            $('#new_wrapper').animate({
                left: '0'
            }, 550).width(windowWidth);
            $('#wrapper').animate({
                left: '-100%'
            }, 550, destroyWrapper).width(windowWidth);
        });
    });
};
clickAnimation();
```

You can view the jQuery code working on my site [HERE](http://swissfish.net/portfolio).

My thought is basically that I want to add some sort of var into the animate function so that I can specify a direction and value. My idea on what I'm looking for is below, although incorrect.

```
$('#new_wrapper').animate({
        directionNew, valueNew
    }, 550).width(windowWidth);
    $('#wrapper').animate({
        DirectionOld, valueOld
    }, 550, destroyWrapper).width(windowWidth);
clickAnimation(directionNew:, 'valueNew', directionOld:, 'valueOld');
```

I don't need the whole thing spelled out, although that never hurts. I am really just looking for some direction on how to create a more correct jQuery navigation/animation here and how to do the code more correctly in the future.

Thanks for all your help guys and forgive me is there is something similar to this on the site, I couldn't find it.

Answer (score 0):

Well the first thing is you have your handler attachment all bound up in the function you want to invert these so the variables are executed inside the function and the handler calls the function. So essentially:

```
$(document).on('click', selector, function (e) {
  var url = $(this).attr('href'),
      // this object (also sometimes called a hash will become the
      // options variable inside of the clickAnimation function.
      // it contains the exact spec. object for jQuery.animate in 
      // the "new" and "old" keys which will be passed as arguemnts
      // directly to the jQuery.animate calls on the #wrapper and #new_wrapper
      // elements. while "url" will be used in the jQuery.load call
      clickargs = {
          "old": { left: '-100%'}, 
          "new": { left: 0 },
          "url": url
      };

  e.preventDefault();

  clickAnimation(clickargs);
});
```

Then your click animation function would be something like:

```
function clickAnimation(options) {
        $('body').append('<div id="new_wrapper"></div>');
        $('#new_wrapper').load(options.url + ' #wrapper', function(){
            $('#new_wrapper').animate(options.old, 550).width(windowWidth);
            $('#wrapper').animate(options.new, 550, destroyWrapper).width(windowWidth);
        });
}
```

You could parameterize this a bit more and make it even more versatile but you get the idea... Also im not cure where you calculate the `windowWidth` and set `destroyWrapper`, but you would need to make sure you configure those inside `clickAnimation` or pass them in via the `options` hash.

Comment: I have never heard of `options` before, is that a jQuery syntax thats just very well hidden or a javaScript thing?

Comment: It's just a parameter that happens to be an object and is called "options". This is a reasonable explanation, but maybe you should buy a Javascript book http://stackoverflow.com/a/4935092/778719

Comment: Yeah you could call `options` whatever you want as long as its a valid variable name. Options is jsut the reference to the hash we pass in to the function `clickAnimation`.

Comment: @Bleepbloop117:  I just refactored a bit and added some notes for better clarity

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be to define directions with javascript objects
for example

```
var toLeft = {
  old_left:'100%',
  new_left:0
  old_top:0,
  new_top:0
}

var toRight = {
  old_left:'-100%',
  new_left:0,
  old_top:0,
  new_top:0
}

var toTop = {
  old_left:0,
  new_left:0,
  old_top:'100%',
  new_top:0
}

var toBottom = {
  old_left:0,
  new_left:0,
  old_top:'-100%',
  new_top:0
}
```

and then give links a class that defines the direction of the upcoming content.

```
<a href="labors.html" class="internal toBottom">Labors</a>
```

After that, you need to make you script decide which way to go

```
var clickAnimation = function() {
    $(document).on('click', linkLeft, function(e) {
        var $this = $(this)
        var url = $this.attr('href');            
        e.preventDefault();

        var direction = null;
        if($this.hasClass('toLeft')) 
          direction = toLeft;
        else if($this.hasClass('toRight')) 
          direction = toRight;
        else if($this.hasClass('toTop')) 
          direction = toTop;
        else if($this.hasClass('toBottom')) 
          direction = toBottom;
        //...same with other classes

        $new_wrapper = $('<div id="new_wrapper"></div>');
        //initial position of new content
        $new_wrapper.css({top:direction.old_top,left:direction.old_left});
        $('body').append($new_wrapper);
        $('#new_wrapper').load(url + ' #wrapper', function(){

            $('#new_wrapper').animate({

                top:direction.new_top,
                left:direction.new_left

            }, 550)
            .width(windowWidth);

            $('#wrapper').animate({

                top:'-'+direction.new_top,
                left:'-'+direction.new_left

            }, 550, destroyWrapper)
            .width(windowWidth);

        });
    });
};
```